# NHibernate: IUserType not working

Tags: nhibernate, fluent, usertype

I have this class that implements IUserType:

```
public class StringToIntType : IUserType
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// mutable object = an object whose state CAN be modified after it is created
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsMutable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public Type ReturnedType
        {
            get { return typeof(StringToIntType); }
        }

        public SqlType[] SqlTypes
        {
            get { return new[] { NHibernateUtil.String.SqlType }; }
        }

        public object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
        {
            var obj = NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeGet(rs, names[0]);

            if (obj == null) return null;

            var s = (string)obj;

            int i;
            if (Int32.TryParse(s, out i))
                return i;
            return -1;
        }

        public void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                ((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = DBNull.Value;
            }
            else
            {
                var i = (int)value;
                ((IDataParameter)cmd.Parameters[index]).Value = i.ToString();
            }
        }

        public object DeepCopy(object value)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object Replace(object original, object target, object owner)
        {
            return original;
        }

        public object Assemble(object cached, object owner)
        {
            return cached;
        }

        public object Disassemble(object value)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

            if (x == null || y == null) return false;

            return x.Equals(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(object x)
        {
            return x == null ? typeof(int).GetHashCode() + 473 : x.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

My mapping:

```
public BarausLangMap()
        {
            Table("BARAUSLANG");

            Id(x => x.ula).CustomType<StringToIntType>();

            Map(x => x.bezeichnung);
            Map(x => x.sprache);
            Map(x => x.la);
            Where("la = 'SPE'");
        }
```

My properties:

```
    public virtual int ula { get; set; }
    public virtual String bezeichnung { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32? sprache { get; set; }
    public virtual String la { get; set; }
```

Problem: When I do

```
var b = session.Get<BarausLang>(5);
```

It says

```
{NHibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type.
Expected: MobileServiceServer.Models.StringToIntType, got System.Int32
```

What is the problem? I thought nHibernate would call StringToIntType implicitely to convert from int to string and vice versa. I think that is the whole point. I thought StringToIntType was only for the mapping? How should I use it then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, `ReturnedType` should return the type that NullSafeGet will return. The example code [you linked to](http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/) is incorrect, `ReturnedType` should return `typeof(bool)`.

Also, getting the Equals method right is very important and I recommend a small change to your code:

```
    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        var xString = x as string;
        var yString = y as string;
        if (xString == null || yString == null) return false;

        return xString.Equals(yString);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I **MAY** have found the problem:

```
public Type ReturnedType
```

above returns StringToIntType, and i **THINK** it should be int.

However, on:

http://lostechies.com/rayhouston/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype/

the method returns the type that implements IUserType.

Please *confirm*.